# Django is rendered blank pages after updating path to re_path

Tags: django

Im new to Django but after solving the orginal issues and changing path to re_path in all my URL files Django now starts the server with no issues. The URLs load but all pages are blank except the home page.
`

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
#from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
re_path('', include('home.urls')),
re_path("users/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), 
re_path("users/", include("users.urls")),  
re_path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
```

My console shows no errors so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.
`

Comment: `^admin/$` (same for the other ones). Why do you change these to `re_path`?

Comment: I’m running in Django 4 and they got rid of path from my understanding @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: no, of `url`...

Comment: I found the problem after reading the documentation a little more. I was misunderstanding what I was reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was done by updating all url.py files.
1st Remove

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

replace with

```
from django.urls import path
```

if any paths start with url simply change to path
for example

```
 url('posts/',views.posts, name = 'posts'),
```

would become

```
 path('posts/',views.posts, name = 'posts'),
```

save the files and rerun the server.